# Merge Two txt files in R using Dates without memory allocation error

Tags: r

The below represents the problem that I am currently facing. I am seeing that the file size increased suddenly and it hangs. I have tried to look for even xdf format but since the file is small it should be a problem.

I have a two files of stock data S&P500 and GE stocks of 1 minute data. there are differences in dates between the two as dataset is not complete. I have to combine the dataset based on common dates between them and then by Time.

GE Stock Data : its around 40 mb till 2015.number of rows = 980465. The Data frame is names as **GE_Last**

```
 Date   Time  Open  High   Low Close Volume
1: 2007-04-27 145900 36.73 36.74 36.70 36.70  40900
2: 2007-04-27 150000 36.71 36.72 36.70 36.71  50100
3: 2007-04-27 150100 36.71 36.73 36.69 36.70 167550
4: 2007-04-27 150200 36.70 36.71 36.68 36.69  81900
5: 2007-04-27 150300 36.69 36.73 36.68 36.71 153500
6: 2007-04-27 150400 36.71 36.72 36.70 36.70  86600
```

S&P500 Stock Data : its around 34 mb till 2015, number of rows 2220101. The dataframe is names **ES_Last**

```
         Date   Time    Open    High     Low   Close Volume
1: 2007-12-09 230100 1517.00 1517.00 1516.75 1516.75      2
2: 2007-12-09 230700 1516.00 1516.00 1515.75 1515.75      2
3: 2007-12-09 230900 1515.50 1515.50 1515.25 1515.25      2
4: 2007-12-09 232700 1516.00 1516.00 1516.00 1516.00      1
5: 2007-12-09 233100 1515.75 1515.75 1515.75 1515.75      1


Combined = merge(GE_Last,ES_Last,by="Date",all.x=TRUE)
```

After doing the merge it throws an error and hangs:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.1 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In NextMethod("[") :
  Reached total allocation of 16296Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In NextMethod("[") :
  Reached total allocation of 16296Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In NextMethod("[") :
  Reached total allocation of 16296Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In NextMethod("[") :
  Reached total allocation of 16296Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Comment: Your Date values aren't unique. So if you have 10 "2007-04-27" in the first data.table and the second data.table as 10 "2007-04-27" records, you'll wind up with 100 records in the merged set. You probably have many more than that which is why you are using up so much memory. Are you sure a `merge()` is the appropriate operation for your data?

Answer (score 1):

As have been pointed out, you should use unique keys if you want your data do merge properly.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr) # string manipulation - just to help recreate data
library(dplyr) # data manipulation
library(lubridate) # times and dates manipulation
library(tidyr) # for tidying data - just to help recreate data
library(sqldf) # using SQL might help with memory issues

# first, lets recreate your data

N = 100000

df1 <- data.table(Date_time = as.character(seq(c(ISOdate(2000,1,1)), by = "min", length.out = N)),
             Open        = rnorm(N, mean = 36),
             High        = rnorm(N, mean = 36),
             Low         = rnorm(N, mean = 36),
             Close       = rnorm(N, mean = 36),
             Volume      = rpois(N, lambda = 40000)) %>% 
  separate(Date_time, c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(Time = str_replace_all(Time, ":", ""))

N = 200000

df2 <- data.table(Date_time = as.character(seq(c(ISOdate(2000,1,1)), by = "min", length.out = N)),
              Open        = rnorm(N, mean = 36),
              High        = rnorm(N, mean = 36),
              Low         = rnorm(N, mean = 36),
              Close       = rnorm(N, mean = 36),
              Volume      = rpois(N, lambda = 40000)) %>% 
  separate(Date_time, c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(Time = str_replace_all(Time, ":", ""))
```

So, now we need to create unique keys. As you said you have 1 minute data, so lets create one minute keys

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(Date_time = ymd_hms(paste0(Date, Time))) # ymd_hms from lubridate is good at converting various date char strings into R dates
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(Date_time = ymd_hms(paste0(Date, Time)))
```

Now that we have the keys, lets merge

```
merged1 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "Date_time", all.x = T)

# or, if you have memory issues, sqldf can help. At least it helped me a few times at work.

merged2 <- sqldf(
  "SELECT df1.* 
    ,df2.Open
    ,df2.High
    ,df2.Low
    ,df2.Close
    ,df2.Volume
   FROM df1
   LEFT JOIN df2
   ON df1.Date_time = df2.Date_time") %>% 
  tbl_dt
```

Answer (score 0):

As [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick) commented, the date does not seem to be a unique key. If you want to keep all the data a quick work around would be to bind the two datasets and then to sort them by date:

```
allData<-rbind(GE_Last,ES_Last)
o<-order(allData$Date)
sortedAllData<-allData[o,]
```

I hope this helps.
Kind Regards

Edit:

Drvi's answer seems correct. I just wanted to add that you can directly do this:

```
merge(GE_Last,ES_Last,by=c("Date","Time"),all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: I am looking for the datasets having common dates between them...ES dataset is smaller as compared to GE Dataset...Hope that clarifies...